# Howto configure a JDBC realm for container managed security with tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, realm

I want to configure tomcat / my web application to use a JDBC realm for container managed security. I specified the realm inside tomcat's server.xml file like this:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" driverName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" connectionURL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hostname:1433/intranet;user=sa;password=sa04jT14;instance=instanceName" userTable="users" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password" userRoleTable="roles" roleNameCol="role" />
```

I created the database and the tables. I created a login-page and added the following code to the web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

But how does Tomcat know which realm he has to use for authentication?
Do I have to add an  element to the  element? But what should be the value then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It's fine so. It depends on the location of the `<Realm>` declaration which one Tomcat will find and use for your webapp. It's also explicitly mentioned in [Tomcat's Realm Configuration HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Configuring%20a%20Realm):

> The `<Realm>` element can be nested
>   inside any one of of the following
>   `Container` elements. The location of
>   the Realm element has a direct impact
>   on the "scope" of that Realm (i.e.
>   which web applications will share the
>   same authentication information):
>
> - *Inside an `<Engine>` element* - This Realm will be shared across ALL
>     web applications on ALL virtual hosts,
>     UNLESS it is overridden by a Realm
>     element nested inside a subordinate
>     `<Host>` or `<Context>` element.
> - *Inside a `<Host>` element* - This Realm will be shared across ALL web
>     applications for THIS virtual host,
>     UNLESS it is overridden by a Realm
>     element nested inside a subordinate
>     `<Context>` element.
> - *Inside a `<Context>` element* - This Realm will be used ONLY for THIS
>     web application.

The `<Engine>` and `<Host>` elements are normally declared in `/conf/server.xml`. The `<Context>` element can be declared in any of the locations as per the list at the bottom of the introductory text of [this documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html). If you for example intend to define this realm in a webapp-specific `<Context>` which you'd like to deploy together with your webapplication without hassling with the server config, then the best place would then be `Webapp/META-INF/context.xml`.

Hope this helps.